# pyqtdeploy: add external modules

Tags: android, python, pyqt, pycrypto, pyqtdeploy

is there someone who has experience with `pyqtdeploy` and adding external modules? I am currently using `pyqtdeploy` (version 1.2) together with `PyQt 5.5.1` to write an application that can be deployed to an Android device. Without any external modules, the freezing with `pyqtdeploy` works pretty well. However, I am not really sure how I can add external modules (not pure Python ones) to my application.

In particular, I want to add the external module `pycrypto`. Therefore, I downloaded the `pycrypto` sourcecode, compiled it with the Android toolchain (from the Android NDK) and now I have a bunch of *.py and *.so files. How can I add them to my application?

My initial attempt was to add the *.py and the *.so files (so basically the whole pycrypto module) to the "Other Packages" tab in pyqtdeploy. 
But now, when I import something pycrypto related in my application (`from Crypto.Cipher import AES`) i get the following error message:

`File: ":/Crypto/Cipher/_AES.py", line 20 in __bootstrap__
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

The _AES.py file where the error is thrown, looks like this:

```
def __bootstrap__():
   global __bootstrap__, __loader__, __file__
   import sys, pkgutil, imp
   __file__ = pkgutil.get_data(__name__,'_AES.cpython-34m.so')
   __loader__ = None; del __bootstrap__, __loader__
   imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
__bootstrap__()
```

At first I thought, that the *.so filename was just wrong and therefore, I got the NoneType Error, so I changed the filename in _AES.py to something other like 'test.so'. Surprisingly, now, I get a different error message than before:

`File ":/pkgutil.py" line 629, in get_data
ImportError: qrcimporter: error opening file :/Crypto/Cipher/test.so`

Ok, so the filename should be fine, right? But why do i get the 'NoneType` error message? What am I doing wrong? Is this the right way to accomplish this?

Any help is highly appreciated. I am pretty sure, that i'm only one small step away from getting this thing to work, but I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: did you get this working? i cant build my app, i am able to build the demo app...